# Solution for slow display of postgis-tables ? (qgis 1.8 + postgis 2.x)

Tags: qgis, postgis, performance

I have the problem that my postgres-tables are displayed very slow when I scroll them in QGIS. I have no problem with other tested GIS (e.g. UDig, GVSig, ArcGIS). The number of objects isn't large (5000-10000) and the rendering is no problem.

I've observed that every action like scrolling causes queries in the database, looks like there's no cache - Is that true??? 'Can't believe that.

The connection to the database server runs through a fast Internet (and it works with other GIS). Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem? I would love to work with QGIS, but the problem makes it impossible so far.

I appreciate your advices, regards Bob

Answer (score 1):

I have a local postgis database with about 10K polygons and found that usability (less flickering and faster dispaly) improves a lot when I set the following options in qgis under the rendering tab.

[image: qgis rendering options]

setting the first option to zero instructs qgis to avoid partial refreshes which IMHO cause a lot of flickering. The second option enables render caching.

I have not found any option with regards to postgis query caching so it might be that qgis hits the database on every scroll/pan.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. So Qgis is currently not able to work with databases that are linked via a (fast) Internet connection. It's a pity because this is a deal breaker. 'Hope this will change with version 2.x. I'll think about how a cache could be developed as in other open source GIS.